# await not working in runInstall

Tags: javascript, shell, async-await, yeoman

I've been using `async/await` code inside a generator that I've been creating and have not faced any issue

```
async prompting() {
  await someFunction()
}
```

But when i try to use this same pattern on `runInstall`, `yarnInstall` or `npmInstall` it seems to fail.

```
async install() {
  this.log('in');
  await this.runInstall('npm', 'mocha', {verbose: true});
  this.log('yahooooooooo');
}
```

The code exits after it reaches the await command. I checked the [code](http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_install.js.html#line29) and it is returning a promise (`yarnInstall` and `npmInstall` internally uses `runInstall`) so no problem there.

I know i can work around this by using `spawnCommandSync`, but that is not the aim of this question.

I want to understand why it is not working or what am i doing wrong? My guess is that it has something to do with `shell` like shell is trying to access another `shell` (not exactly this, but something along the lines).

Comment: What is `runInstall` does it return a promise.?

Comment: @Keith [runInstall](http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_install.html#.runInstall) is a `yeoman` API. It executes package manager's (like `npm`) install commands on shell. Yes, it does return promise.

Comment: "*The code exits after it reaches the await command.*" - what do you mean by "exits"? Does it immediately log `yahoo`? If not, does it throw an error maybe?

Comment: @Bergi, no CLI returns the control back to the user after logging `in`. No error or any other message.

Comment: OK, it might not log an error, but that doesn't necessarily mean that none happened :-) Did you try explicitly catching and logging?

Comment: Where/how do you call `install`? And does the npm command actually run (quietly, obviously) or does it not do anything?

Comment: @Bergi `runInstall` internally calls `spawnCommand` which has the job of calling `npm install`. The install command will run just like how you run it from CLI directly, printing all the logs and in my case after it is finished yeoman will return control of CLI back to the user.